# regular expression generation

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression

```
"[a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9]"
```

From this i  want to generate a regular expression exclude the characters `D`, `F`, `I`, `O`, `Q` and `U`.
That is `"Q3D4R5"` should not be included.

How should i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead to exclude those characters from your string.

```
(?!.*[DFIOQU])(?:[a-z][0-9]){3}
```

[http://www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/1ishptG5nJ)

Some explanations:

`(?!.*[DFIOQU])` checks the complete string if there is a occurrence of a character from the character group, if so then the whole thing is False.

`(?:)`defines a non capturing group that is repeated 3 times `{3}`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches only lowercase characters, so I assume you want to exclude d, f, i, o, q and u .

You can rewrite your original regex as

```
   ([a-z][0-9]){3}
```

This regex you can modify to

```
([a-ceghj-nprstv-z][0-9]){3}
```

to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[a-ceghj-nprsv-z]
```

instead of

```
[a-z]
```

Answer (score 0):

if case matters then to filter the letters part:

`[a-zA-CEGHJ-NPRSV-Z]`

this will allow any lower case letter but not the upper case ones specified.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in other answers, you can include specific characters as well as more specific ranges in suare brackets; assuming your regexp matching is not case-sensitive (otherwise your original example presumably wouldn't be working), you could have:

```
"[a-ceghj-nprsv-z][0-9][a-ceghj-nprsv-z][0-9][a-ceghj-nprsv-z][0-9]"
```

Now if you also want to validate length (if there's any possibility that you had a value like "A1A1A1A", and you did NOT want that to match), then you'd also need to detect the start and end of the expression, eg:

```
"^[a-ceghj-nprsv-z][0-9][a-ceghj-nprsv-z][0-9][a-ceghj-nprsv-z][0-9]$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this "regular expression editor" web site: http://www.rubular.com/
very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the following two cases at http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/ and they appear to work.

^(?!.*D.*)^(?!.*F.*)^(?!.*I.*)^(?!.*O.*)^(?!.*Q.*)^(?!.*U.*)[a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9]

[a-ce-ghj-npr-tv-z][0-9][a-ce-ghj-npr-tv-z][0-9][a-ce-ghj-npr-tv-z][0-9]